Is there a way to create copy a folder from sharepoint onto blob using logic app?
I need to set up a logic app,  if there is a change inside a folder_1(folders inside folder_1), a create blob will run which will take all the folders inside folder_1 and copy it onto the blob. I want to copy the all folders inside folder_1.
Example sharepoint stucture: Folder_1 main folder AND F1-3 are subfolders
Folder_1
  F1
  F2
  F3


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Can you provide more details

@RithwikBojja
What I would like to do is, use logic app to automate folders(from sharepoint) being copied to a blob.
Currently from my understanding this is not possible, as you are not allowed to put folders onto azure blob, only files. I have over 10k files. But if i can copy all the folders in one go i won't need to iterate over 10k folders.


use logic app to automate folders(from sharepoint) being copied to a blob.

To copy files from a list you can follow below design:


Output:

To copy files in folder structure from all lists:

then:

